# How to convert convexhull polygon from geodataframe to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, geometry-conversion

I have a point geodatafram with a `class`column. I wanted to make a convexhull for each class and then write it as a shapefile. but I got error to convert it to shapefile.

```
print(gdf.head())
```

[image]

```
Convexhull = gdf.dissolve("Class").convex_hull.reset_index().set_geometry(0)
print(convexhull.head(10))
```

[image]

```
Convexhull.to_file("r'P:/.../convexhull.shp",driver='ESRI Shapefile')

error:
    if driver == "ESRI Shapefile" and any([len(c) > 10 for c in df.columns.tolist()]):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit buggy but apparently you cant have a column name which isn't a string, you have at least one column named `0`

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/100points_wgs84.shp')

df.rename({'columnabc':1}, inplace=True, axis=1) #rename one column to the integer 1
df.to_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/100points_wgs84_test.shp')
#TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

df.columns = [str(col) for col in df.columns] #Convert all column names to strings, 1 to '1'
df.to_file(r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/100points_wgs84_test.shp')
#Now it is working
```